# Clojure: combination of binding and map acting weird?

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure at the moment, and I'm not getting the logic behind this code:

```
(def ^:dynamic *max-value* 250)
(defn valid-value? [v]
  (<= v *max-value*))

(binding [*max-value* 500]
  (prn (map valid-value? [299]))
  (map valid-value? [299]))
```

It prints `(true)`, but returns `(false)`.
I realized the answer as I finished typing. I guess I'll post the question anyway,
maybe it will be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` generates a lazy sequence, which evaluation isn't forced until the repl prints the value, in this case.

At that point, `*max-value*` is no longer bound to 500.

If you use `mapv` instead, `[true]` will be returned!